# Pass 2-dimensional data in the Multivariate normal density function of python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, computer-vision, gaussian

I want to calculate the Gaussian PDF of two dimensional data, i am trying to do this in python using `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal` function but i don't understand how can i pass my data into it?

Is `multivariate_normal` only used for analyzing one dimensional data in n-dimensions or can I use for my data set also?

```
data set-> X = [X1,X2....Xn]
```

where each

```
Xi=[x1 x2]
```

is 2 dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compute the density function, use the `pdf()` method of the object [`scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html).  The first argument is your array `X`.  The next two arguments are the mean and the covariance matrix of the distribution.

For example:

```
In [72]: import numpy as np

In [73]: from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

In [74]: mean = np.array([0, 1])

In [75]: cov = np.array([[2, -0.5], [-0.5, 4]])

In [76]: x = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1], [0.5, 0.25], [1, 2], [-1, 0]])

In [77]: x
Out[77]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  1.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  1.  ],
       [ 0.5 ,  0.25],
       [ 1.  ,  2.  ],
       [-1.  ,  0.  ]])

In [78]: p = multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov)

In [79]: p
Out[79]: array([ 0.05717014,  0.04416653,  0.05106649,  0.03639454,  0.03639454])
```